# Consume SSL web Service IIS using Domino 9.0.1

Tags: eclipse, web-services, ssl, iis, lotusscript

I cannot connect to the Ssl Web Service, I have this error in my log :

```
2018-02-16 16:37:37   Agent 'ObtenirDossier 1.6|ObtenirDossier 1.6' error: Web Service IMY1W016SignalerTacheRealiserDossElec_n1 method SignalerTacheRealiserDossElec error (0) null
```

The web service receive a 500 error when he see me trying to connect, he doesn't recognize me even if I use
an account who have the rights to consume the web service. The web service see me like anonymous.

I have TLS 1.0.
I look with this error but didnt found so much.  I enable my notes.ini for `DEBUG_SSL_ALL=3`. So here is a part of what the logs say:

```
[08B0:0066-1264] 2018-02-16 15:59:16,44 CompleteNTIRequest> Enter
[08B0:0066-1264] 2018-02-16 15:59:16,44 CompleteNTIRequest> Event = 256 Status = 9 Bytes = 0
[08B0:0066-1264] 2018-02-16 15:59:16,44 CompleteNTIRequest> Exit
```

Here is my code in my webservice :

```
Call srv_MY118.SetCredentials( "User","MotdePasse" )    
Call srv_MY118.SetSSLOptions( NOTES_SSL_ACCEPT_SITE_CERTS + NOTES_SSL_SEND_CLIENT_CERT + NOTES_SSL_V30_WITH_V20_HELLO )
Set srv_Retour  = srv_MY118.SignalerTacheRealiserDossElec( srv_Param, srv_Fault_Tech, srv_Fault_Fonc )
```

I notice too this entry in another log on the server , I was wondering if it was part of the problem :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2018-02-16 15:40:13.627
!MESSAGE Unable to find feature.xml in directory: e:\data\notessrv_2\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse\features\org.openntf.services.feature_9.0.1.v09_01_20171023-1055.jar

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2018-02-16 15:40:14.854
!MESSAGE Could not install bundle ../../shared/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.domino.http.ssl_9.0.1.20151122-0905.jar   Bundle "com.ibm.domino.http.ssl" version "9.0.1.20151122-0905" has already been installed from: initial@reference:file:../../shared/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.domino.http.ssl_9.0.1.20151122-0905.jar/
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: TLS/SSLv3 is considered to be a security risk.  Many (maybe most) servers these days are being configured to reject TLS/SSLv3 connections, and require TLS 1.2 instead.  What does your IIS server accept.

Comment: I'm on TLS 1.0 it's my mistake. I'm waiting for the answer what the server accept. I will come back with the answer.   Thanks.

Comment: There is some information about fixes for Domino to add TLS 1.2 support here https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/TLS_1.2 and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21698222, but the first one covers inbound connections to Domino, and the second covers Java agents. You used a LotusScript tag on your question, though, so it's not clear to me whether either of them covers your use case.